# creating a css ribbon - can create in header replicating in footer doesn't work

Tags: html, css

Here's the code http://jsfiddle.net/4XSjz/

I've basically copied the same info from the `h1` header that I created where it works, when changing that for the `h4` tag and the footer it doesn't. Is it because I have too many elements? I want it to stick to the bottom too, which I've managed to do and I can see the edges of the ribbon just not the middle part.

Thanks

PS: I just realised I Had no background colour - ok that's fine, then I want to have the ribbon without the cut away parts and to overlap upwards not downwards?

**Elaboration :** Ok so I have the ribbon in the code above, with the background colour given a colour it will create the appropriate background colour for that ribbon creating the css ribbon.

What I would like to do is keep the ribbon but remove the cutaways the triangles essentially. Then I want to have the overlap where its darkest colour and have it above the rectangle.

Something like this:

```
 /_/________________\_\
/-----------------------\
```

I hope that clarifies it somewhat

Comment: Presumably you want to see the `background-color`? Of the `h4` or the `span` *within* the `h4`? Because the `h4` background-color is `transparent`. So...presumably the `span`? Which doesn't *have* a `background-color` set.

Comment: that's right - I noticed that and fixed that. How would I go about resolving the issue of removing the ribbon cuts, and having an overlapping ribbon without the cuts but withthe overlap being above the ribbon not below it?

Comment: I haven't looked that closely, I was just curious about what was going on with the lack of assigned colours. I'll take a look; but it's near the end of a long day. So, I might not have time to respond, but I'll look in tomorrow if I don't tonight. You'll probably, hopefully, have received an answer long before then, though.

Comment: I just wanted to notify you that I have absolutely no idea what your issue is or what you're trying to accomplish. Likely I'm not the only one, so I'd recommend elaborating a bit on your question

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try and replace the h4 in the CSS with .footer - it refers to the class, not the object.